# How to add link to mysql database record as a <html> href?

Tags: php, html, mysql, records

```
  if($rezultat = $polaczenie->query($sql))
$ilu_userow = $rezultat->num_rows;
  while($ilu_userow>0){
    $wiersz = $rezultat->fetch_assoc();
    $id = $wiersz['id'];
    $like = $wiersz['likes'];
    $price = $wiersz['price'];
    echo '<div class="pozycja">
            <span>
              <h1><font color="blue"/> '
               . $id . ' </h1></font><font color="red"/> '
                . $like . ' </font><h2><strong><font color="green"/> '
                 . $price . '</h2></strong></font></span></div>';

    $ilu_userow = $ilu_userow - 1;
  }
```

This is my code, and - as in the topic - i want to create html adress to every row i get from my database, and the question is - how?

Comment: read about htmlspecialchars() , mysqli_escape_string(), htmlentities()

Comment: i have got htmlentities() in my code, but i need to get html adress to the every record i get from my database

Comment: Do you mean something like: `<a href="file.php?id=$id">$id</a>` ?

Comment: yes, exactly. Can U do that?

Comment: That is how you would do that im2be. within your while statement you would have `<a href="viewpage.php?id='.$id.'">'.$pagename.'</a>` And then you can go as far as having only one viewpage.php and running your content through includes or database structures using `$_GET`

Comment: Do you mean: For each row printed on the page, I want to be able to generate a unique URL that corresponds to THAT row. So when a user goes to that specific URL, it will bring them to that specific row on the page. (?)

Comment: no, not row on the page, but just row of variables in by database - i am creating auction website and i need unique URL to every auction which i get from my db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if($rezultat = $polaczenie->query($sql)) $ilu_userow = $rezultat->num_rows;   while($ilu_userow>0){
    $wiersz = $rezultat->fetch_assoc();
    $id = $wiersz['id'];
    $like = $wiersz['likes'];
    $price = $wiersz['price'];
    echo '<div class="pozycja">
            <span>
              <h1><font color="blue"/> '
               . $id . ' </h1></font><font color="red"/> '
                . $like . ' </font><h2><strong><font color="green"/> '
                 . $price . '</h2></strong></font></span>';

    //added line start

    echo '<a href="file.php?id='.$id.'">'.$id.'</a>';
    echo '</div>';

    //added line end

    $ilu_userow = $ilu_userow - 1;   }
```

Comment: OK, it works, but when i am entering generated URL, it shows mi just index.php - not the auction site

Comment: How does your link look like? Instead of `file.php` you should use your PHP script file that reads through `$_GET['id']` the id of the product that was clicked. Also please provide the auction site url.

Comment: I am not using $_GET method in my code when getting records from db, should I?

Comment: Well, you should read about passing variables through the url: http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/get-post-request . When you click on one product, its id from the DB is sent through the url, you need another script to fetch the value of the id and do whatever.

Comment: maybe I will try another way, to create unique URL for my auction like index.php/this-is-an-example-auction.html. Could I?